# What is the best way to alter image style in view for a teaser

Tags: 7, views, media

I have an image style set for all my nodes for teasers.  There is one view that I need it to display differently.  Is there a way I can alter in code?

I know that I can just change my setting from **Content** to **Field** and modify the image style that way but I am looking for a way that I can do it in code.

Answer (score 2):

While I would generally just access this from the **field** output type from the View. I would recommend looking into some theme adjustments (and preprocessing Views). Since you are outputting content to the Teaser, you could add some additional verification from the template (https://www.drupal.org/node/53464).

Some helpful links would be:

- [template_preprocess_views_view_fields](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/7)
- [theme_image_style](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/theme_image_style/7)